# How to clean up "a type was inferred to be `Any`" warning?

Tags: scala, warnings, typing

I have the following code:

```
class TestActor() extends RootsActor() {

  // Receive is a type resolving to PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
  def rec2 : Actor.Receive = {   
    case "ping" => println("Ping received!!!")
  }

  def recAll = List(super.receive, rec2)

  // Compose parent class' receive behavior with this class' receive
  override def receive = recAll.reduceLeft { (a,b) => a orElse b }
}
```

This functions correctly when run, but it produces the following warning:

```
[warn] /Users/me/git/proj/roots/src/multi-jvm/scala/stuff/TestActor.scala:18: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
[warn]  override def receive = recAll.reduceLeft { (a,b) => a orElse b }
[warn]                                                   ^
```

How can I change this code to clean up the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get a warning for your code. What if you use orElse without reduce?

```
scala> import akka.actor._
import akka.actor._

scala> class RootActor extends Actor { def receive = { case _ => println("bang") }}
defined class RootActor

scala> class TestActor extends RootActor {
     |   def rec2: Actor.Receive = { case "ping" => println("ping") }
     |   override def receive = super.receive orElse rec2
     | }
defined class TestActor

scala>
```

Answer (score 3):

you must have `-Xlint` compiler flag when you compile the code. Looks like this warning indeed was added in 2.11.x. And it's a bug in scalac (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9211) as if you remove type alias (from orElse argument) it works fine

```
$ scala -Xlint
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_80).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> type Problem = PartialFunction[Any,Unit]
defined type alias Problem

scala> def moreProblems(problem1: Problem, problem2: Problem) = problem1 orElse problem2
<console>:8: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
       def moreProblems(problem1: Problem, problem2: Problem) = problem1 orElse problem2
                                                                                ^
moreProblems: (problem1: Problem, problem2: Problem)PartialFunction[Any,Unit]

scala> def moreProblems(problem1: PartialFunction[Any, Unit], problem2: Problem) = problem1 orElse problem2
<console>:8: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
       def moreProblems(problem1: PartialFunction[Any, Unit], problem2: Problem) = problem1 orElse problem2
                                                                                                   ^
moreProblems: (problem1: PartialFunction[Any,Unit], problem2: Problem)PartialFunction[Any,Unit]

scala> def moreProblems(problem1: Problem, problem2: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) = problem1 orElse problem2
moreProblems: (problem1: Problem, problem2: PartialFunction[Any,Unit])PartialFunction[Any,Unit]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because Akka's default Actors are untyped. That means that every message that you pass is type of Any and than it is matched by pattern matching. So either you put type in reduceLeft arguments or just ignore warning.

Answer (score 0):

This new warning was introduced with Scala 2.11